# Linux Perl: How to look for the existence of a file and read it, if it exist -> REALTIME

Tags: linux, perl, sleep, daemon

There are similar questions like this, but what I am after is the real time detection of a file existence.

I have 2 linux box/PC.

[Linux Box 1]
-> Generates a file named **host** (Manually executed)

[Linux Box 2]
-> Has a daemon that sleeps every 2 seconds checks if the expected file exist. And if it exist it will execute my ssh command (ofc ourse a bunce of text will show up showing that it was executed bla bla bla).

**PERL SCRIPT:**

```
ctr:
if (-e $file) { system ("ssh $script $host.$display"); } 
sleep(2);
goto ctr;
```

**THE PROBLEM**
The problem is, it seems that I can't determine if the file exist real time even though it already exist.

**BOX 1**

```
[machine01:/home/machine01]% /MACHINE/TOOLS/perl/app/host_gen
> executed at 08/21/2015 21:40:32
```

**BOX 2**

```
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:22]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:24]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:26]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:28]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:30]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:32] **<-expected execution**
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:34]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:36]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:38]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:40]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:42]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:44]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:46]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:48]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:50]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:52]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:54]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:56]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:40:58]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:00]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:02]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:04]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:06]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:08]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:10]
Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:41:12] <- It was executed here
TYPE_AND_DISPLAY [wkss machine01.ult.ultera.omps.com:0]
TYPE [wkss] DISPLAY [machine01.ult.ultera.omps.com:0]
```

It would take almost like a minute or sometimes after 10 seconds to detect the existing file.

Its just weird.

You guys have any idea how could I achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At what point in that sequence of print statements was the file created?

Comment: Please don't use `goto` for flow control. You are killing cute little kittens with that, and your maintenance programmer will hate you forever. Use a loop instead.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen , At about Sleeping for 2 seconds [08/21/2015 21:01:34], bottom line of it is, it wasn't detected on the time expected.

Comment: @simbabque , I heard about those anti goto. But for me, sometimes, its useful and neat. :)

Comment: The script output you're showing us does not match the code you've posted.  What is the real code you ran which generated that output?

Comment: If the file is being generated on box1 and the script that checks for the existence of the file is on box2, how is it doing that check?  Is the value of $file a unc path pointing to the file?  Is box2 connecting to box1 via an nfs mount?

Comment: @RonBergin , Thanks for mentioning that. I have a mount directory (network drive / filer) on both box.

Comment: The script that generated the file opened it at 08/21/2015 21:40:32 but when did it close the file?  Was it closed at 08/21/2015 21:41:12?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Prior serverfault.com question: How can I tell if a file is on a remote filesystem with Perl?](https://serverfault.com/questions/278349/nfs-detecting-remotely-created-files-programmatically)

Quoted from that thread;

> By default, most NFS clients cache directory information for 60 seconds.

Solution noted in that thread:

> Mount the NFS share on the client with the noac option to disable attribute caching, or use acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0 to just disable directory caching.

Comment: It was configured like this on the mtab: 10.10.10.10:/vol/dir/app nfs rw,intr,hard,addr=10.10.10.10 0 0 Must I still add those you suggested? acdirmin=0,acdirmax=0

Comment: the file was generated @ 08/21/2015 21:40:32, the file then was acknowledge as existing @ 08/21/2015 21:41:12

Comment: I have not done any testing myself, but that is the reported working solution to the problem you're having so yes, you should add one of suggested fixes to your nfs config and test it.

Comment: Thanks alot @RonBergin